# Auto foreign key in django models

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

It is possible to do this in Django. I have models and I want every new user to register in Model User and automatically in models Customer in foreign key register

```
class Customer(models.Model):
                     here auto 
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11,null=True)
    likecus=models.ManyToManyField(smartphone ,verbose_name="b",null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "User: {}, phone: {}".format(self.user, self.phone)
```

Comment: You can do that with `post_save` signal or by overriding `save()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `post_save` [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save).

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(post_save, sender=get_user_model())
def create_customer(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        # if your user model has phone, if not remove phone.
        Customer.objects.create(user=instance, phone=instance.phone)
```

Or the second method if you have the custom user model. Override the `save()` method:

```
class YourUserModel(...):
    ...

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        created = not self.pk
        super().save(*args,**kwargs)
        if created:
            Customer.objects.create(user=self, phone=self.phone)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need to extend user model, then it's not obligatory to use separate model. You may use [profile model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) instead.

Comment: it's just that I have a lot of resources in django  and It didn't work at all